# 2 Spinner with different style in same project

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles

Surfing the web I've found [this site](http://android-holo-colors.com/) which generates Android custom themes. I've used it to create my personal theme: it inherits from Android:Widget.Holo (should be the dark one with white text) and some fancy widget witha a custom color. 
Because the theme inherits from *Android:Widget.Holo*, I have dark background and white text; but in some activity i need the opposite: white background with dark text.

When it comes to change the text color of most item i can do it easily using `android:textColor="@android:color/black"`, but when i try to use it on `spinner` item it does nothing.

I've tried to create a new style only for spinner items, but i canno't apply it...

This is the first style generated (white text on black background):

```
<style name="SpinnerAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/apptheme_list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    </style>
```

And this is the second I've generated (the opposite, back text on white background):

```
    <style name="SpinnerDarkTextAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/apptheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

But when I use `style="@style/SpinnerDarkTextAppTheme` nothing happens.

How can I do to have 2 different styles (obviously working at the same time) for my spinners?

**SOLVED** using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078822/3816340) piece of code.

Comment: Add the spinner style at runtime....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two themes in the XML and switch between them before you set the content view:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390025/2219600

Another approach:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16101936/2219600

Comment: I've tried both, but that's not what I need. I want to change color of  **displayed text**.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but how can I use 2 different style for displayed text (one on dark background and one in white background) on spinner? Also the entries are loaded from a string-array